# gnuplot use index in the function(tanh) in for loop

Tags: function, loops, indexing, gnuplot

I'm trying to make command for gnuplot.
from column 8 to 33, using tanh
so I tried below command

```
plot for [i=1:26] 's0' u 1:(i*0.1+2):(tanh($(7+i))) w l lw 3 palette notitle
```

it doesn't work.

So I tried several time while searching internet

```
plot for [i=1:26] 's0' u 1:(i*0.1+2):(tanh("$(7+i)")) w l lw 3 palette notitle
Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected
plot for [i=1:26] 's0' u 1:(i*0.1+2):(tanh("${7+i}") w l lw 3 palette notitle
Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected
plot for [i=1:26] 's0' u 1:(i*0.1+2):("tanh($(7+i))") w l lw 3 palette notitle
warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

However, I couldn't solve.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the `column` function.  To quote the docs:

> `column(x)` may be used only in expressions as part of `using` manipulations
>    to fits or datafile plots.  It evaluates to the numerical value of the contents
>    of column x. See `plot datafile using`.

So you would want something like:

```
plot for [i=1:26] 's0' u 1:(i*0.1+2):(tanh(column(7+i))) w l lw 3 palette notitle
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do. Thank you very much